# Connect pages in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, path, connection, single-page-application, document

My mission is to upload a website in SharePoint and to connect its pages.

I uploaded the pages in Documents, created a page in Pages, and added the main page.

I tried to connect the next page with href and action but none of it is working because the path is incorrect.

How can I find the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

If uploading pages inside Documents/Pages library, you can get the page absolute url from UI:

Documents library:

[image]

Pages library:

[image]

You can use the page url in href property to build hyperlink.